# Replacing a dropdown on a form with another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdownbox

I have a form that has a drop-down of dates. What I want to do is for the dates to not appear until another drop-down has an option selected because this other drop-down will determine what dates show and what ones don't.

I have created two drop-down menus one without the dates that will display until the other drop-down has an option selected and another with all of the dates in. How can I get this one to appear exactly where the one without the dates was?

I am a novice when it comes to jQuery and JavaScript I have tried a couple of basic things but it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please post a example of the code you have tried so far and possibly a jsfiddle with what you've got.

Comment: With jQuery, you could use a `hide()` and a `show()` on the elements, accordingly.  That handles the display.  But I upvoted the comment that says you need to provide more info and a JSfiddle.  I suspect you won't get much help from folks until they see that.

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xxr7kLcs/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery change event

```
$("#form").change(function() { // some logic here });
```

Here is jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/a92b40w9/

Here you can get some smart stuff about events in jQuery https://api.jquery.com/category/events/ pay attention to those associated with form and input